# sap.m.ObjectListItem: Need to keep whitespace (tabs) in title

Tags: sapui5

```xml
<ObjectListItem
  title="{i18n>uBOMItem}: {Item}         Component: {ComponentDesc}"
  number="{ComponentNo}"
>
```

I am using `sap.m.ObjectListItem`. While binding, I need tab space between `{Item}` &  `{ComponentDesc}`.

E.g. like `\t`

Answer (score 1):

Currently, `sap.m.ObjectListItem` does **not** support rendering whitespace for title.
And I agree with [alexP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55114826/5846045) that it's not clean to combine multiple labels (`"{i18n>uBOMItem}:"` and `"Component:"`) into one.
That being said; **if it's really necessary** to do so, however, you'll need to extend ObjectListItem.

Example: [https://embed.plnkr.co/WaMaP4wqMevsjMxX](https://embed.plnkr.co/WaMaP4wqMevsjMxX?show=custom%2FObjectListItem.js,preview)

> [image]

Internally, ObjectListItem renders its title from `sap.m.Text`. The Text control has a public property called `renderWhiteSpace`<sup>[api](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Text/methods/setRenderWhitespace)</sup> which we can use to allow tabs to be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectListItem` is only for one value. In your case it's better to use `CustomListItem`.

```
<CustomListItem>
  <HBox width="100%">
    <VBox>
      <Label emphasized="true" text="{i18n>uBOMItem}: {Item}" />
    </VBox>
    <VBox class="sapUiSmallMarginBegin">
      <Label emphasized="true" text="Component: {ComponentDesc}" />
    </VBox>
    <VBox width="50%" justifyContent="End">
      <ObjectNumber number="{ComponentNo}" />
    </VBox>
  </HBox>
</CustomListItem>
```

It's not clean to output two data bindings from your model in one label, text or similar. You should split the output. In case of an i18n label and a data binding in one control i would make a exception.